# Subprocess Popen and PIPE in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

The following code prints an empty line as an output which is false.
The problem is not in the permissions, since I tested the command with 777 permissions for the pdf -file. **How can you fix the command to give a right output?**

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
output = Popen(['pdftotext', '/home/aal/Desktop/lkn_pdf/appa.pdf'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: unrelated: In Python 2.7+, you could write it as `output = check_output(['pdftotext', '/home/aal/Desktop/lkn_pdf/appa.pdf', '-'])` if you want to raise an exception for non-zero exit status.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: the comment is for visitors from google due to the question title. But `check_output` vs. `.communicate` has nothing to do with your real issue: providing output filename as `-` so that `pdftotext` writes to the pipe (its stdout) and that part is already answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pdftotext creates a file by default. To send the result to standard output, use:

```
pdftotext file.pdf -
```

or in Python:

```
output = Popen(['pdftotext', '/home/aal/Desktop/lkn_pdf/appa.pdf', '-'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```