# Python 2.6: Get input from bash command with Popen and communicate and store as variable

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I need to get the input from a Bash command and store it as a Python variable (sprice; a single float). On Python 2.7 the following works well:

```
bashCommand = "curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=vwrl.as&f=l1'"
sprice = float(subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True))
```

However on **Python 2.6 check_output isn't available**. Instead we have to use:

```
proc = Popen(['curl', '-s', 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=vwrl.as&f=l1'], stdout=PIPE)
print (proc.communicate()[0].split())
```

Which shows the float we're after, enclosed by brackets.

```
['40.365']
```

Which is all right if I want to see the output and be done. But I need to **store it in a Python variable like in the previous (2.7) case**. However when I try to assign it to a variable I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "arr.py", line 49, in <module>
    sprice = proc.communicate()[0].split()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 791, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

**Which is the proper way to do this?**

Comment: version of check_output that will work with python2,6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580663/save-error-message-of-subprocess-command/29580739#29580739

Comment: related: [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/4279)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My  syntax was wrong. This Q&A gets it straight.

[Subprocess Popen and PIPE in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836588/subprocess-popen-and-pipe-in-python)

So the command is:

> Popen(['curl', '-s', 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=vwrl.as&f=l1'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

Comment: the code in your question should work as is i.e., you can write `p = Popen(...)` and later `sprice = p.communicate()[0]`. What syntax error exactly may lead to `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`? You have to call `proc.output.close()` to cause the error.

Comment: I don't know, but the error appears, nonetheless. With this syntax everything goes well and the objective is achieved.

Comment: I don't see any difference that matters. Could you provide a [standalone example that causes ValueError](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: No need. This works as intended. Isn't the information in the question enough to reproduce this?

Answer (score -1):

```
import commands
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl -s http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=iwda.as&f=l1")
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput):

> Execute the string cmd in a shell with os.popen() and return a 2-tuple
>   (status, output). cmd is actually run as { cmd ; } 2>&1, so that the
>   returned output will contain output or error messages.